# "Cannot convert argument from Class<T>* to Class<T> &&" on list insert

Tags: c++

In C++, I've constructed a basic class such as this:

```
class MyList {
protected:
    list<MyOtherClass<int>> nodes;
    int size;
...
}
```

However later on in MyList when I try to insert a value into my nodes list, such as:

```
MyOtherClass<int>* temp = new MyOtherClass<int>(size);
nodes.push_back(temp);
```

I receive a compilation error saying

```
cannot convert argument 1 from 'MyOtherClass<int> *' to 'MyOtherClass<int> &&'
```

I've racked my brain and have tried everything I could think of to fix it. Thoughts?

Comment: C++ is not like Java, C# or any other language that has a variant of `new`. You should be avoiding `new` in modern C++ more often than not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the type was not compatible. You list is of type `list<MyOtherClass<int>>` and `temp` is of type `MyOtherClass<int>*`. Try this:

```
MyOtherClass<int> temp(size);
nodes.push_back(temp);
```

or this:

```
class MyList {
protected:
    list<MyOtherClass<int> *> nodes;
    int size;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> However later on in MyList when I try to insert a value into my nodes list, such as:
>
> ```
>  MyOtherClass<int>* temp = new MyOtherClass<int>(size);
>  nodes.push_back(temp);
> ```
>
> I receive a compilation error

That's because you are not inserting a `MyOtherClass<int>` value. You are inserting a pointer to an unnecessarily dynamically-allocated `MyOtherClass<int>` value. Don't do that.

Just create the new object in the normal fashion:

```
MyOtherClass<int> temp(size);
nodes.push_back(temp);
```

Or even:

```
nodes.emplace_back(size);
```

Usually (and unless you are writing some library code or an allocator) when you have written `new`, you have made a mistake, or momentarily forgot what language you were writing in. :) And yes I know there are a million "tutorials" on the web telling you to `new` things. They are wrong.